# Using A couple of Temp variables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Trying to get this working. I realize that select into creates a table, not a variable so I'm not sure how to do this:

```
select state.state_id into stateId from state where state.name = 'Illinois'
    
INSERT INTO public.city(
    name,
    state_id)
VALUES ('Chicago', stateId);

select public.city.city_id into chicago from public.city where public.city.name = 'Chicago'

INSERT INTO public.location (
city_id,
state_id,
country_id,
name)
VALUES (
    chicago,
    9,
    185,
    'Chicago, IL, USA'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for variables here, you can query as you're inserting. Just be sure that your query returns only the one row you want.

```sql
INSERT INTO public.city (name, state_id)
SELECT 'Chicago', state.state_id
FROM state 
WHERE state.name = 'Illinois';

INSERT INTO public.location (city_id, state_id, country_id, name)
SELECT public.city.city_id, 9, 185, 'Chicago, IL, USA'
FROM public.city 
WHERE public.city.name = 'Chicago';
```